# How to get enumitem to play nice with hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, enumitem

How can I get the `\nameref` command of the `hyperref` package to work while the `enumitem` package is loaded? The following gives an error while removing the `enumitem` fixes it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \item [{Test\label{Test}}] Some text
\end{description}

\nameref{Test}

\end{document}
```

I tried to change the order of the packages but that does not help either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\enit@descriptionlabel@hook[1]{}
\def\enit@description@i#1#2#3#4{%
  \ifnum#1>#3\relax
    \enit@toodeep
  \else
    \enit@list{}%
      {\let\enit@type\tw@
       \advance#1\@ne
       \labelwidth\z@
       \enit@align@left
       \let\makelabel\descriptionlabel
       \enit@style@standard
       \enit@preset{#2}{#1}{#4}%
       \enit@calcleft
       \let\enit@svlabel\makelabel
       \def\makelabel##1{%
         \NR@gettitle{##1}%
         \labelsep\z@
         \ifenit@boxdesc
           \enit@svlabel{\enit@align{\enit@format{\enit@descriptionlabel@hook{##1}}}}%
         \else
           \nobreak
           \enit@svlabel{\enit@format{\enit@descriptionlabel@hook{##1}}}%
           \aftergroup\enit@postlabel
         \fi}%
       \enit@before
       \enit@negwidth}%
     \enit@keyfirst
  \fi}

\usepackage{hyperref} 
\AtBeginDocument{\let\descriptionlabel\NRorg@descriptionlabel}
\renewcommand\enit@descriptionlabel@hook[1]{\NR@gettitle{#1}#1}
\begin{document}


\begin{description}
  \item [{Test}\label{Test}] Some text
\end{description}

\nameref{Test}

\end{document}
```

So to get it working enumitem must add a hook, and hyperref must then use it.

Comment: Apparently it's not "the best we have" :)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for checking. I get ``! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...el \fi }\enit@before \enit@negwidth
l.42 \item
[{Test}\label{Test}] Some text
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.``

Comment: Is your enumitem version up-to-date?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. Updating my system did the trick! Any idea why the author of enumitem does not fix his package in this way? Or is there a downside?

Comment: I wrote to the enumitem maintainer. If he changes enumitem, I can adapt nameref to get it working directly.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with `enumitem` documented in section 12.2 of the documentation. The workaround suggested there is to let `\makelabel` to `\descriptionlabel` in the `before` code of the list, and that indeed seems to work, but as Ulrike points out in the comments, it's not really a complete solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[before=\let\makelabel\descriptionlabel]
  \item [{Test\label{Test}}] Some text
\end{description}

\nameref{Test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: but this break e.g. the format key, so it is only a work-around.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, I think that's clear from the docs. But unless Javier fixes it, I guess it's the best we have?