# Enumitem with hyperref's \nameref, in complex environments

Tags: hyperref, enumitem, nameref

I provide this pre-amble of my main desired output, having been told that my below approach is inherently misguided (due to `\nameref` not being designed or able to obtain only a numeral, instead of a descriptive label).

I would nonetheless like to be able to have a command, like `\nameref`, that given a label retrieves the `enumerate` counter associated with its respective item.

My goal is to be able to refer to `enumerate` `item`s in both a single (as currently accomplished with `\ref`) and multiple-label contexts. For example, I would like to be able to continue to do `\ref{<label1>}`, but also to do something like `\multirefs{<label1>, <label2>}` and have this result in the following outputs:

`\ref{<label1>}` : (A_{1})  ← this currently works

`\multirefs{<label1>, <label2>}` : (A_{1}, A_{2}) ← this is what I would like

I am, however, most interested in more general approaches, similar to the [linked answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500401/134641).

---

I am trying to get `\nameref` to work properly with [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). To do so, I am using the preamble code provided in the [existing answer on this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500401/134641).

I am then wrapping the document code from that answer, within a custom command, as shown below (and partly adapted from [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167517)):

```
\newcommand{\labelleditem}[1]{%
                                 \stepcounter{enumi}%
                                 \item[{\theenumi{}}\label{#1}]%
                             }
```

I want to make use of the [`description` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500401/134641), with the optional arguments of an `enumerate` environment, as follows:

```
\begin{description}[label={($\text{A}_{\arabic*}$)}, series=name, resume=name]
    \labelleditem{Broken} XXX
    \item XXX
\end{description}
```

This does not work, presumably in part due to the [`description` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500401/134641) not fully-implementing or making accessible the [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) optional arguments.

To clarify, I only wish to use the `enumerate` list, as shown in the below MWE. I do not, however, know how to properly adapt the [existing answer on this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500401/134641), which uses a `description` list, to an `enumerate` list.

How might I be able to get this to work, similar to the [existing answer on this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500401/134641), but with my additional specifications, shown above?

Alternatively, how can I get `\nameref` to work via a more general or direct patch to [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)?

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\enit@descriptionlabel@hook[1]{}
\def\enit@description@i#1#2#3#4{%
  \ifnum#1>#3\relax
    \enit@toodeep
  \else
    \enit@list{}%
      {\let\enit@type\tw@
       \advance#1\@ne
       \labelwidth\z@
       \enit@align@left
       \let\makelabel\descriptionlabel
       \enit@style@standard
       \enit@preset{#2}{#1}{#4}%
       \enit@calcleft
       \let\enit@svlabel\makelabel
       \def\makelabel##1{%
         \NR@gettitle{##1}%
         \labelsep\z@
         \ifenit@boxdesc
           \enit@svlabel{\enit@align{\enit@format{\enit@descriptionlabel@hook{##1}}}}%
         \else
           \nobreak
           \enit@svlabel{\enit@format{\enit@descriptionlabel@hook{##1}}}%
           \aftergroup\enit@postlabel
         \fi}%
       \enit@before
       \enit@negwidth%
       }%
     \enit@keyfirst
  \fi}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{\let\descriptionlabel\NRorg@descriptionlabel}
\renewcommand\enit@descriptionlabel@hook[1]{\NR@gettitle{#1}#1}

\newcommand{\labelleditem}[1]{%
                             %\label{#1}%
                             \stepcounter{enumi}%
                             \item[{\theenumi{}}\label{#1}]%
                             %
                             }
% -------------------------------------

\begin{document}


\begin{description}
  \item [{Test}\label{Test}] Some text
\end{description}

\begin{description}[label={($\text{A}_{\arabic*}$)}, series=name, resume=name]
    \labelleditem{Broken} XXX
    \item XXX
\end{description}

\nameref{Test}

\nameref{Broken}

\end{document}
```

The above produces:

[image: Compiled output of the above MWE]

It also outputs the following error:

```
Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.57 ...}_{\arabic*}$)}, series=name, resume=name]
```

I also provide this MWE on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/qksfrntnjpgs).

Comment: Your goal is quite unclear. You seem to mix a description list with an enumerate list, but add the numbers only for some items. Why are you doing this?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, that's not my intention. I just don't know how to properly adapt the linked solution to an enumerate-based list. I only want an enumerate list, but I'd like it to work with `\nameref`, as implemented in the `description` modifications from the linked answer. I must just be misunderstanding how that was done, and I'm not sure how to adapt it.

Comment: Enumerate lists don't have "names" only numbers  so what do you expect to get back?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The numbers themselves, e.g. `(A_{1})` vs., say, `(A_{10})` , in this example.

Comment: That is, I'd like to be able to do, e.g., `\hyperref[\nameref{<label>}]{<label>}`, obtaining, say, `(A_{1})`, that properly links to that item.

Comment: Have you looked at `cleveref`? As far as I can tell, it has already invented the wheel you want.

Comment: @cfr It does indeed, but unfortunately I need this to work with `hyperref`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/516339/134641) provided on a more recent iteration of this question has proven sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments I guess that you don't want description or nameref but simply an enumerate list with a special label:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={(A\textsubscript{\arabic*})}, series=name, resume=name]
    \item\label{test} XXX
    \item XXX
\end{enumerate}

\ref{test}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I really need `\nameref` to function, as poorly attempted in my question. This simple approach is what I am already using, but I need `\nameref` to work for my custom command `\labelleditem`, as shown in my (admittedly broken) MWE.

Comment: I don't see what nameref has to do with your command. It simply increases a counter and doesn't set a name.

Comment: Well, that's fair enough, but I nonetheless wish to use `\nameref` to manually construct more complex references. I thought I could elide those details, but my eventual goal is to have the option to construct, e.g., `(\hyperref[\nameref{<label1>}]{<label1>}, \hyperref[\nameref{<label2>}]{<label2>})`, to produce, say, (A_{1}, A_{2}), where each properly links to their items.

Comment: You are misunderstanding nameref.

Comment: How so? I want to _encode_ the `enumerate` numeral into the `nameref`-retrievable label. I realize that will require patching, beyond its present configuration, but why can't `nameref` be used in that manner?

Comment: Because you don't want to retrieve a name, you want the normal ref(s).

Comment: But I don't (or at least I don't think I do). I do indeed want to obtain names, in the form of the labelled numerals, to permit my construction of more complex references, involving multiple items.

Comment: For a section ref gives the number and nameref gives the title. There is nothing similar in an enumerate. It only has a number, there is no text that nameref can retrieve. Stop to cling on the nameref idea and better describe what you really want, so that someone can tell you how to implement it.

Comment: I'd still quite like for it to retrieve the number, but very well. Apologies for the lack of clarity. I will try to edit the question accordingly.

Comment: I have now edited the question, to hopefully provide a better exposition of my goal. I really appreciate your engaging with me on this! Please let me know if my question is still not sufficiently clear.

Comment: better ask a new question. This one is quite a mess already. (But I don't see what you gain by an additional \multiref compared to \ref{A}, \ref{B}.)

Comment: The difference in this example is (A_{1}), (A_{2}) vs, (hopefully, once corrected) (A_{1}, A_{2}).