# Use of hyperref to dynamically refer to enumerated items, in complex environments

Tags: hyperref

I would like to be able to have a command, like `\nameref`, that given a label, retrieves an `enumerate` counter associated with its respective item.

My goal is to be able to refer to `enumerate` `item`s in both a single (as currently accomplished with `\ref`) and multiple-label contexts. For example, I would like to be able to continue to do `\ref{<label1>}`, but also to do something like `\multirefs{<label1>, <label2>}` and have this result in the following outputs:

`\ref{<label1>}` : (A_{1})  ← this currently works

`\multirefs{<label1>, <label2>}` : (A_{1}, A_{2}) ← this is what I would like

I am most interested in more general approaches, similar to [a linked answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500401/134641). While [`cleverref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) provides functionality equivalent to this, for the purposes of this question, please presume that it cannot be used, and that [`hyperref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) must be used (though can be patched).

How might I be able to get this to work, similar to the [existing answer on this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500401/134641), but with the above conditions?

---

N.B. due to the intended general nature of this question, no MWE is provided. This question constitutes a new attempt at my [prior equivalent question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511662), which admittedly became convoluted. Thanks to [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) for their prior useful comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to process a list of labels you can do it like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,hyperref}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\multirefs{m}
{
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq
    {
      \exp_not:N\ref{##1}
    }
  (\seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {,~})
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\section{a}\label{sec:a}
\section{b}\label{sec:b}
\multirefs{sec:a,sec:b}
\end{document}
```

[image]